# Do I need to stripslash that I saved using a model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

This is something that has been troubling my mind for quite a while since I been using the CakePHP framework. Do I need to sanitize or strip slash content that I had originally saved via a model?

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

By default, it protects your from SQL injection, but for XSS protection and such you either need to enable the [**Security component**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html) or use the Sanitize library.  As it says in the book:

> CakePHP already protects you against SQL Injection if you use CakePHP’s ORM methods (such as find() and save()) and proper array notation (ie. array(‘field’ => $value)) instead of raw SQL. For sanitization against XSS it’s generally better to save raw HTML in database without modification and sanitize at the time of output/display.

You might find [**this page**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html) of the book particularly interesting for further reading.

Comment: Yes I know that the framework automatically takes care of sql injection during saving. But when selecting data do I need to apply stipslahes?

Comment: Why do you think you would need to? Are you seeing unexpected backslashes in your `find()` results?

Comment: @ElGabbu Normally, no you would not need to do that. Cake uses prepared and escaped statements using the DBO engine of PHP, so that does all the required work for you.

Comment: He's talking about the data received from datasources i guess. In case [`magic_quotes_runtime`](http://php.net/magic_quotes_runtime) is active, the data might be slashified.